# Derivation of the one-form potential in Kerr-Newman spacetime--Sean Carroll GR

Tags: general-relativity, potential, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations, kerr-newman-metric

In Sean Carroll's GR book, he gives the non-vanishing components of the one-form potential of a Kerr-Newman blackhole,[image: eq (6.74)]

I am not sure how to derive this just from the metric itself. I looked at some sources that derive the potential $A$ by solving the inhomogeneous Maxwell's equation, given that the current $J$ is known. But, I do not know what the field $F^{\mu\nu}$ or $J^\mu$ looks like in this case, since we are just given the metric.

One possible way to derive this is to solve the De-Rham wave equation for $A$ (which in-turn comes from solving the homogeneous Maxwell's equation):[image: De-Rham Wave equation]

Here, $R^i_j$ is the Ricci tensor, and (assuming) the d'Alembertian is $\Box = g^{ji}\nabla_j\nabla_i $. However, to solve this, I think we would need to guess a form of $A$. I know that $A^i$ is a four-vector so we could solve the equation for each component of $A$, individually. Say, we pick the t component $i=t$, and use the fact that $i=j$ (because of the Kronecker delta). So, now we only need to solve $$ g^{tt}\nabla_t\nabla_t A^t - R^t_t A^t=0   $$
But how should I solve this analytically? Should I expand this out to $g^{tt} \nabla_t (\partial_t A^t - \Gamma^t_{\mu t}A^t) -R^t_t A^t = 0$? If so, how do I go further from here?